# WebView - Opção atualizar aparece somente uma vez em onReceivedError, veja mais

Tags: java, android, webview

Olá, estou desenvolvendo um projeto para meu site, e ate então está ficando muito legal.
Só que tive um probleminha e é o seguinte, sempre que a página der error eu chamei a feature Snackbar, ficando assim:

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
        Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(snackbarCoordinatorLayout, "ERRO NA CONEXÃO", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE);
        snackbar.setAction("Atualizar", new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                webView.reload();
            }
        });

        View sbView = snackbar.getView();
        TextView textView = (TextView) sbView.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
        textView.setTextColor(Color.RED);

        snackbar.show();
    }
```

Até então, tudo bem, a página quando da error a feature é mostrada, quando o  usuário seleciona "Atualizar" e a página continua dando error a feature continua persistindo ... Só que eu não quero deixar a página de error original, então criei uma página em html e chamei junto com a Snackbar, ficando assim:

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/error.html");
        Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(snackbarCoordinatorLayout, "ERRO NA CONEXÃO", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE);
        snackbar.setAction("Atualizar", new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                webView.reload();
            }
        });

        View sbView = snackbar.getView();
        TextView textView = (TextView) sbView.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
        textView.setTextColor(Color.RED);

        snackbar.show();
    }
```

Só que nessa hora que vem o problema, eu chamando essa "custom página de error" a feature Snackbar aparece somente uma vez, ou seja apenas pela primeira vez que a página da error, daí quando o usuario seleciona "Atualizar" mesmo a página dando error novamente ela não aparece mais.
Ou seja, essa página de error está atrapalhando em alguma coisa, você pode me ajudar? Como faço para que os dois funcione, sendo que a feature funcione sem problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema está em quando você passa a função `reload()` para o `WebView`, ele está recarregando a sua página de erro que você passou anteriormente, e não a sua página original.

Faça o seguinte, antes de carregar sua página de erro personalizada, armazene a página original em uma variável:

```
String urlOriginal = webView.getUrl();   
webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/error.html");
```

E na sua função `onClick(View v)` você carrega novamente a url original:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
   webView.loadUrl(urlOriginal);
}
```

Dessa forma a página de erro será exibida, e caso o usuário clique para atualizar, a página original será mostrada ao invés de atualizar a página de erro.

Comment: Peeeeeeeerfeito era exatamente isso amigo. MUUITO obrigaado.